# QGIS Value Map widget / look up table

Tags: qgis, widget, attribute-form

I have two tables: One, where I digitize water pipes (A) and a second one with pipe-types(B, not mappable). The pipe-types layer contains several columns like `type`, `material`, `diameter_inside`, `diameter_outside` etc. When I digitize a pipe in my layer, I just want to select via dropdown menu one of the types which are included in the pipe-types layer. All the other fields should then be automatically filled with the corresponding information.

So far, I only get my drop-down menu via layer properties -> attribute forms -> widget type "value map" and selecting the type-layer here. How can I reach the autofill function for the other fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one suggestion: continue using the value map where the data is derived from a pipe_types layer - this can be a non-spatial layer which just contains the look-up data.
Edit the settings in the water_pipes layer for each field that has to be filled with data from the pipe_types layer with an expression like this in the default text box:
[image]

```
map_get(attributes(get_feature('pipe_types','pipe_type',attribute('type'))),'pipe_material')
```

Where the syntax is like this:

```
map_get(attributes(get_feature(lookup-layer name,join fieldname in lookup-layer,attribute(join fieldname in this layer))),fieldnamefor the value you want)
```

Make sure you check the *Apply default on update* setting ON.

This is what the expression looks like in the expression editor:

[image]